# How to translate this MySQL statement into named_scope method?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

"select * from users, awards where (users.id = awards.user_id) and awards.trophy_id not in (select awards.trophy_id from awards where awards.trophy_id = #{trophy.id})"

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Named scopes are used on single models; do you want to get the users or the awards? Also, the inner select statement looks like it will always return only `trophy.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered own question:

named_scope :not_awarded_trophy, lambda { |trophy| 
    { :include => :awards, :conditions => [ "awards.trophy_id not in (select awards.trophy_id from awards where awards.trophy_id = ?)", trophy.id ] }
  }